# Sanity.io, is any way to to change field type painlessly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, headless, sanity

I have quite a lot documents in the sanity.io with completed fields. There is a need to change field type. And  here are the problem:

[image]

Now I need to rewrite this field from old to the new and delete old field in each document. But it is expensive for me, I have a lot of documents. Is there any way to move data from one field to another once for all documents?

Comment: @kmelve I had hope that you knew the subject.

Comment: Please, don't push "minus" without real reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a great question! There's currently no way to do this through the studio user interface, but it's possible to write a data migration script that does this. Please see the example here: https://www.sanity.io/docs/migrating-data#migrate-using-the-api

This example is for renaming a field, but I believe it should be possible to modify it for changing the type name as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!